# Black page in DOMPDF

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I know that this is also questioned but the answers i found didnt help me...

Im trying to make this simple pdf file with DOMPDF:

```
<?php
require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
$html =
'<html> 
<head>
<style>
@page {margin-top: 0;margin-left: 0;
    }
.paginapdf{margin:10mm;
}
</style> 
</head>
<body><div class="paginapdf" style="background-color:red; width:277mm;    height:190mm"><p>Hola</p></div></body></html>';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper("A4", "landscape");
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("pdf".Date('Y-m-d').".pdf");
?>
```

And it works, but the first page is a blank page...

I think the problem is that im using all the A4 paper. If i change the `.paginapdf` margin to 1mm for example, the blank page doesnt appears...

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You're only setting the page margin to zero on the top and left, but you should set it to zero for all sides (since there is a default page margin).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, fixed...

I changed `@page` margin to 10mm and deleted the `.paginapdf` margins, now it works... why? i dont know hahaha